# Complexity for single-linkage clustering with max norm

Tags: reference-request, computational-geometry

Let $S\in\mathbb Z^d$ be a set of points, with some notion of distance $d(x,y)$ between two points $x,y\in S$. I am specifically interested in the *max distance*, that is $d(x,y)=\max_{1\le i\le d} |x_i-y_i|$ where $x=(x_1,\dotsc,x_d)$ and $y=(y_1,\dotsc,y_d)$.

[Single-linkage clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-linkage_clustering) consists in computing a tree $T$ on the set $S$ of *minimal distances*, that can be defined by the following algorithm that computes the set $E$ of edges of $T$ as follows:

1. Set $E=\emptyset$ *[each point is a cluster]*
2. While $|E|<|S|-1$, add to $E$ a pair $(x,y)$ such that

   - $x$ and $y$ are in distinct connected components of $T$;
   - $d(x,y) = min_{u,v} d(u,v)$ where the minimum is taken over all pairs of points $u$, $v$  that are in distinct connected components of $T$.

If one first computes all the distances between pairs of points in $S$ and sort them, the above algorithms allows to compute the tree $T$ in time $\tilde O(n^2)$ if one assumes that the distance can be computed in time $O(1)$. Here the notation $\tilde O(\cdot)$ hides poly-logarithmic factors.

> What is the complexity of computing this tree, when the distance is the max distance?
>
> - If $d=2$, is there a quasi-linear algorithm (that is in time $\tilde O(n)$)?
> - More generally, if $d$ is fixed, is there a quasi-linear algorithm?
> - Or is there a quadratic lower bound (in some *reasonable* model)?

*Note: I asked a [similar question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/41528/complexity-of-clustering-lattice-points) some days ago on cs.sx. I had no answer, so I re-post it here with a new (and I guess better) formulation.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Single-linkage clustering gives the same connections in the same order that you would find using Kruskal's algorithm for the minimum spanning tree, and the clustering can be found by finding a minimum spanning tree and then running Kruskal's algorithm on the resulting $(n-1)$-edge graph. Therefore, the time is bounded by the MST construction + the time to sort the edges of the MST.

The two-dimensional $L^\infty$ MST can be constructed in $O(n\log n)$ time using rectilinear Voronoi diagrams, and an $O(n\log n)$ algorithm for the three-dimensional version is given by

Krznaric, Drago; Levcopoulos, Christos; Nilsson, Bengt J. (1999),
Minimum spanning trees in $d$ dimensions,
*Nordic J. Comput.* 6 (4): 446–461.

more generally an algorithm that is within a polylog factor of linear for any fixed dimension is given by

Gabow, Harold N.; Bentley, Jon Louis; Tarjan, Robert E. (1984), Scaling and related techniques for geometry problems, *Proc. 16th ACM STOC*, pp. 135–143, [doi:10.1145/800057.808675](http://doi.org/10.1145/800057.808675)